# How to return function result in GraphQL

Tags: python, django, reactjs, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using React, Apollo and GraphQL at the frontend and Django, Python and Graphene at the backend.

I want to implement search_bar and when user click on search button I want to execute GraphQL query with the user input.

At the backend I want to grap that string and I want to pass it to an function and then returned result from the function I want to pass back to the frontend.

I have code as follows:

**FRONTEND**

```
export const GET_RESULTS = gql`
query SearchVinResults($vin: String!){
  searchVinResults(vin: $vin) { 
        id
        label
        url
   }
  }`;


class VinSearch extends Component {       
    onVinSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {value, client: {query}} = this.props;
        query({query: GET_RESULTS, variables: { vin: value }});
    }

    render() {
        const {value, clearSearch, onChange} = this.props;
        return (
            <SearchField
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                clearSearch={() => clearSearch()}
                value={value}
                clearIcon="fal fa-times"
                placeholder="Search VIN"
                withButton={true}
                buttonStyles={{borderLeftWidth: 0}}
                onClick={e => this.onVinSearch(e)}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default withApollo(VinSearch);
```

**Backend**

class Query(object):
    search_vin_results = ????  # What do I need to do here

```
def resolve_search_vin_results(self, info, **kwargs):
    # Here I want to do something like

    vin = info['vin']
    results = get_vins(vin)
    return results
```

Any idea?